# Unimported library crashing pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a script that works flawlessly, well, more accurately it does what I need it to. However, when I try to convert it to an EXE using auto-py-to-exe, it acts weird and doesn't compile. It begins to error out when loading module 'matplotlib' which I don't even import. Below is the pyinstaller script (changed paths and names accordingly)

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --icon "C:/path/to/file.ico" --name "NameOfScript" "C:/path/to/file.py"
```

Here is everything that is imported in the script

```
import requests
import imageio
import datetime
import urllib
import fnmatch
import os
from os.path import basename
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pyodbc
from PIL import Image
from PIL import TiffImagePlugin
from PIL import ImageSequence
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import string
import random
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
from datetime import timezone
import time
import traceback
```

Any ideas as to why it would import matplotlib? I can provide the entire output of auto-py-to-exe if needed

Below is the error output from the command line during execution:

```
c:\>auto-py-to-exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '_get_data_path'
c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
Cannot find ('matplotlib\mpl-data\DumpStack.log', 'DumpStack.log', 1, 'x')
317423 ERROR: An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 672, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Jmorgan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjh3locwt\FS EBE BOL.spec", line 20, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 438, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(self.toc, cdict=kwargs.get('cdict', None),
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 200, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 286, in assemble
    archive = CArchiveWriter(self.name, srctoc + mytoc,
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 333, in __init__
    super(CArchiveWriter, self).__init__(archive_path, logical_toc)
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._add_from_table_of_contents(logical_toc)
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 89, in _add_from_table_of_contents
    self.add(toc_entry)  # The guts of the archive.
  File "c:\users\jmorgan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 411, in add
    fh = open(pathnm, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'DumpStack.log'
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide the complete error you get. even if any of the modules you are importing used `matplotlib`, it should get included in the final executable file without any error really

Comment: @Matiiss I added in the complete error

Comment: did you try to run the `pyinstaller` as admin? open the console as admin and then run the pyinstaller code

Comment: I did not. However, adding the command `--exclude-module "matplotlib"` did allow the EXE to be created, and it seems to be working properly. I'll keep testing it and make sure it is good.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the exe to compile by adding in the exclude module and telling it to omit matplotlib

```
--exclude-module "matplotlib"
```

This allowed the exe to finish and compile and work as intended